# How to revert keras sequential model to a state previous to build?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2

I want to reuse the same model architecture but with different datasets, that is, to programmatically change the input layer to a different shape, and reset model parameters if needed.

Something along the lines of

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential(
           tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)
)

optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam()

losses=[tf.keras.losses.mean_absolute_percentage_error]

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=losses)

model.build(input_shape=(None,2))
# ... train model and evaluate

model.unbuild() # this doesn't exist
model.build(input_shape=(None,3))
# ... train model and evaluate on different dataset
```

Anyone knows a clean way to perform this?

Comment: Wrap the model creation in a function you can easily call multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one backbone model and reuse it to build as many models as you want with different inputs layer, the backbone model's parameters will remain the same for all new model you create, build new backbone model if you want reset parameters, example code here:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
import numpy as np

input_shape_b = (16, )
# Backbone model
def build_backbone_model():
    inputs_b = layers.Input(shape=input_shape_b)
    h = layers.Dense(256, 'relu')(inputs_b)
    outputs_b = layers.Dense(1, 'sigmoid')(h)
    return models.Model(inputs_b, outputs_b, name="Backbone")
    
backbone_model = build_backbone_model()
backbone_model.summary()

def new_model_reuse_backbone(input_shape, name):
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
    h = layers.Dense(input_shape_b[0], 'relu')(inputs)
    outputs = backbone_model(h)
    return models.Model(inputs, outputs, name=name)

# Will use backbone model we defined before
new_model_0 = new_model_reuse_backbone((32, ), "new_model_0")
new_model_0.summary()

# Rebuild will reset backbone model's parameters
backbone_model = build_backbone_model()
new_model_1 = new_model_reuse_backbone((256, ), "new_model_1")
new_model_1.summary()
```

Outputs:

```
Model: "Backbone"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 16)]              0
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 256)               4352
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 257
=================================================================
Total params: 4,609
Trainable params: 4,609
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Model: "new_model_0"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         [(None, 32)]              0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 16)                528
_________________________________________________________________
Backbone (Functional)        (None, 1)                 4609
=================================================================
Total params: 5,137
Trainable params: 5,137
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Model: "new_model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)         [(None, 256)]             0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 16)                4112
_________________________________________________________________
Backbone (Functional)        (None, 1)                 4609
=================================================================
Total params: 8,721
Trainable params: 8,721
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Thank you for the clean solution. Using the tf.keras.Model with the sequential model as backbone is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Glad to help : )